# REST-style URLS and PHP

Tags: php, rest, get

I'm having a really hard time getting my head around using REST-style URLS.  Can I get a little help with this?  Right now I have a query string like so:

`example.com/calendar_expanded?date=1270094400`

I have a mod rewrite that's hiding the .php extension.  How do I

1. Make this `calendar_expanded/date/1270094400` happen.
2. `$_GET` the values from the url after the fact?

I love the concept behind it but working 16-hour days to meet a deadline for an entire month is taking a toll on my brain.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perhaps just update your rewrite rule to something like: `RewriteRule ^calendar_expanded/date/([0-9]+)$ calendar_expanded.php?date=$1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create quite a lot REST URLs you should consider to use a PHP framework that makes use of the [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) design pattern.

This way, every request is processed by the framework and you are flexible to design your URLs however they should look like.

E.g. [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) supports a RESTful design out of the box.

BTW RESTful URLs only make sense if the parameters are somehow fixed and specify a resource, for example the title of a blog post. If you want to pass a parameter only to e.g. control the sorting of a table (i.e. the view of something) then this should go as a "normal" GET parameter into the query string.

In your case it looks like you want to control what day should be shown in a calendar. I personally would just use the normal GET query string here.

Comment: As does Kohana, a framework we use at my job.  It defaults to routing a url like this example.com/my_controller/controller_method/param1/param2 to a controller called to a method called "controller_method" inside a controller called "my_controlled" with paramaters "param1" and "param2"... pretty neato.

Comment: I think this is the most correct answer and Felix you looked at what I actually wanted to do.  You're right, I'm passing date variables around to control a calendar.  I guess I'll stick with my existing format.  I'm going to read up on this though because I feel like it might come in handy at some point. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for making the distinction between REST and just nice looking URLs.  I've seen some confusion where people think that by using URL rewriting, they're making their app RESTful - which isn't always the case.

Answer (score 3):

You need to inspect `$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]` or `$_SERVER[ 'PATH_INFO' ]`, not `$_GET`.

`$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]` will hold this `/calendar_expanded/date/1270094400?quertStringParams=1&etc...`
`$_SERVER[ 'PATH_INFO' ]` will hold this `/calendar_expanded/date/1270094400`

In other words, you will have to break down these values into their seperate segments, by using `explode()` and the likes. I suggest you use `$_SERVER[ 'PATH_INFO' ]` as a subject, since the real query string variables will be available in `$_GET` already.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ calendar_expanded.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This is what I remember CakePHP doing when it first came out... dunno if it still does...