# Special profile page link like www.domain.com/username

Tags: php

Hey guys I have a question. I wanna create a profile page for each new user, and I noticed that on facebook you could simply type in www.facebook.com/username and you get to the user's page, my question is, how can I do this without something like domain.com/users.php?useraname="username" or something like that? How can I simply make it like the facebook one?

Comment: mod_rewrite is your friend here (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is mod_rewrite. This will allow you to write PHP code that appears to the end user to be a directory on the server (such as www.facebook.com/user.php?username into www.facebook.com/username.)

An introduction to them with PHP can be found here: http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

Please note you will need to enable it on your server. That should be possible in the .htaccess file if you're running an Apache server.

Comment: Would this be correct? 
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /users.php?username=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer since I'm NOT a php guy

What you're looking for a RESTful urls, mostly you can get urls like that on your web app if you use a framework that supports restful urls

See this SO question:
[REST-style URLS and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121069/rest-style-urls-and-php)

See this article:
http://blog.garethj.com/2009/02/building-a-restful-web-application-with-php/

[Search google](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=restful+urls+in+php&qscrl=1) and [Search SO with google](http://www.google.com/search?q=restful+urls+in+php&sitesearch=stackoverflow.com/questions&qscrl=1)

Answer (score 0):

This can’t be done with PHP alone. It’s the web server that needs to know how to handle these kind of request first.

Because, to put it simply, a web server just takes the requested and tries to map it onto a file in the file system below the document root directory. And if it can’t find an appropriate file, it returns an 404 error code.

Now there is some kind of [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) mechanism for almost every web server software. In case of Apache as the most popular web server software out there, there is [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) that allows URL rewriting based on rules. In this case the following could enable `/users.php?username=username` being also accessible through `/username`:

```
RewriteEngin on
RewriteRule ^[a-z]+$ index.php?username=$0
```

Answer (score 0):

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /php/profile
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)*$ ./profile.php

http://exapmle.com/users/waqar.alamgir

in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] you will see users/waqar.alamgir