# How to get parameter only, if full url inside variable in php?

Tags: php

My code:

```php
$url = "https://www.example.com/reset_password/6f88e62e492ed288200b99b09f6d8132";
$para = $this->uri->segment($url);
echo $para;
```

In this code I only want the parameter that is passed in the url i.e `6f88e62e492ed288200b99b09f6d8132` but it's not working. How can I get only the parameter in php?

Comment: What do you get from `$this->uri->segment($url);`?

Comment: nothing @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica

Comment: Okay. Try `$para = array_reverse(explode('/', $url))[0];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [REST-style URLS and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121069/rest-style-urls-and-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use explode function.

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$exploded_url = explode("/",$url);
$code = $exploded_url[1];
```

Comment: Sorry i typing it on iPhone and there is no this quotes

Comment: Thanks very much